# Unity project error CS0136: A local variable named `distanceBall' cannot be declared in this scope because

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script that gives me the error:

> Assets/Soccer Project/Scripts/Player_Script.cs(493,11): error CS0136: A local variable named 'distanceBall' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to `distanceBall', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else

I can't find any good answers online and don't know how to fix it, here's the script:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class Player_Script : MonoBehaviour {

    // player name
    public string Name;
    public TypePlayer type = TypePlayer.DEFENDER;
    public float Speed = 1.0f;  
    public float Strong = 1.0f;
    public float Control = 1.0f;


    private const float STAMINA_DIVIDER = 64.0f;
    private const float STAMINA_MIN = 0.5f; 
    private const float STAMINA_MAX = 1.0f; 


    public enum TypePlayer {
            DEFENDER,
            MIDDLER,
            ATTACKER
        };

    public Vector3 actualVelocityPlayer;
    private Vector3 oldVelocityPlayer;
    public Sphere sphere;
    private GameObject[] players;
    private GameObject[] oponents;
    public Vector3 resetPosition;
    public Vector3 initialPosition;
    private float inputSteer;
    private const float initialDisplacement = 20.0f;    
    public Transform goalPosition;
    public Transform headTransform; 
    [HideInInspector]   
    public bool temporallyUnselectable = true;
    [HideInInspector]   
    public float timeToBeSelectable = 1.0f; 
    public float maxDistanceFromPosition = 20.0f;   

    public enum Player_State { 
           PREPARE_TO_KICK_OFF,
           KICK_OFFER,
           RESTING,
           GO_ORIGIN,
           CONTROLLING,
           PASSING,
           SHOOTING,
           MOVE_AUTOMATIC,
           ONE_STEP_BACK,
           STOLE_BALL,
           OPONENT_ATTACK,
           PICK_BALL,
           CHANGE_DIRECTION,
           THROW_IN,
           CORNER_KICK,
           TACKLE
          };

    public Player_State state;
    private float timeToRemove = 3.0f;  
    private float timeToPass = 1.0f;

    // hand of player in squeleton hierarchy
    public Transform hand_bone;

    public InGameState_Script inGame;

    public Texture barTexture;
    public Texture barStaminaTexture;
    private int barPosition=0;
    private Quaternion initialRotation; 

    public float stamina = 64.0f;   




    void  Awake () {

        GetComponent<Animation>().Stop();
        state = Player_State.PREPARE_TO_KICK_OFF; 
    }



    void  Start (){

        // get players and oponents and save it in both arrays

        players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PlayerTeam1");
        oponents = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("OponentTeam");


        resetPosition = new Vector3( transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z );

        if ( gameObject.tag == "PlayerTeam1" )
            initialPosition = new Vector3( transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z+initialDisplacement ); 

        if ( gameObject.tag == "OponentTeam" )
            initialPosition = new Vector3( transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z-initialDisplacement ); 

        // set animations speed to fit perfect movements        
        GetComponent<Animation>()["jump_backwards_bucle"].speed = 1.5f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["starting"].speed = 1.0f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["starting_ball"].speed = 1.0f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["running"].speed = 1.2f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["running_ball"].speed = 1.0f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["pass"].speed = 1.8f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["rest"].speed = 1.0f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["turn"].speed = 1.3f;
        GetComponent<Animation>()["tackle"].speed = 2.0f;

        GetComponent<Animation>()["fight"].speed = 1.2f;    
        // para el movimiento de la cabeza de los jugadores

        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("rest"); 

        initialRotation = transform.rotation * headTransform.rotation;
    }


    // control of actual player 
    void Case_Controlling() {

        if ( sphere.inputPlayer == gameObject ) {

            if ( sphere.fVertical != 0.0f || sphere.fHorizontal != 0.0f ) {

                oldVelocityPlayer = actualVelocityPlayer;

                Vector3 right = inGame.transform.right;
                Vector3 forward = inGame.transform.forward;

                right *= sphere.fHorizontal;
                forward *= sphere.fVertical;

                Vector3 target = transform.position + right + forward;
                target.y = transform.position.y;

                float speedForAnimation = 5.0f;

                // if is owner of Ball....
                if ( sphere.owner == gameObject ) {

                    if ( GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("rest") ) {
                        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("starting_ball");
                        speedForAnimation = 1.0f;
                    }

                    if ( GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("starting_ball") == false )
                        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running_ball");

                }
                else {

                    if ( GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("rest") ) {
                        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("starting");
                        speedForAnimation = 1.0f;
                    }

                    if ( GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("starting") == false )
                        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running");

                }


                transform.LookAt( target );
                float staminaTemp = Mathf.Clamp ((stamina/STAMINA_DIVIDER), STAMINA_MIN ,STAMINA_MAX );
                actualVelocityPlayer = transform.forward*speedForAnimation*Time.deltaTime*staminaTemp*Speed;
                transform.position += actualVelocityPlayer;


                // if get a radical diferent direction of player change animation...        
                float dotp = Vector3.Dot( oldVelocityPlayer.normalized, actualVelocityPlayer.normalized );

                if ( dotp < 0.0f && sphere.owner == gameObject ) {

                    GetComponent<Animation>().Play("turn");
                    state = Player_State.CHANGE_DIRECTION;
                    transform.forward = -transform.forward;
                    sphere.owner = null;
                    gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = false;
                    sphere.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(  -transform.forward.x*1500.0f, -transform.forward.y*1500.0f, -transform.forward.z*1500.0f );
                }


            } else {

                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("rest");
            }


            // pass
            if ( sphere.bPassButton && sphere.owner == gameObject ) {
                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("pass");
                timeToBeSelectable = 2.0f;
                state = Player_State.PASSING;
                sphere.pressiPhonePassButton = false;
            }

            // shoot
            if ( sphere.bShootButtonFinished && sphere.owner == gameObject ) {
                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("shoot");
                timeToBeSelectable = 2.0f;
                state = Player_State.SHOOTING;
                sphere.pressiPhoneShootButton = false;
                sphere.bShootButtonFinished = false;
            }


            if ( sphere.bPassButton && sphere.owner != gameObject ) {
                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("tackle");
    //          timeToBeSelectable = 2.0f;
                state = Player_State.TACKLE;
                sphere.pressiPhonePassButton = false;
            }



        } else {

            state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;

        }

    }

    // ask if someone is in front of me
    bool NoOneInFront( GameObject[] team_players ) {


        foreach( GameObject go in team_players ) {

            Vector3 relativePos = transform.InverseTransformPoint( go.transform.position ); 

            if ( relativePos.z > 0.0f )
                return true;        
        }

        return false;

    }


    // Oponent control
    void Case_Oponent_Attack() {

        actualVelocityPlayer = transform.forward*5.0f*Time.deltaTime;
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running_ball");
        Vector3 RelativeWaypointPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(goalPosition.position);
        inputSteer = RelativeWaypointPosition.x / RelativeWaypointPosition.magnitude;
        transform.Rotate(0, inputSteer*10.0f , 0);
        float staminaTemp = Mathf.Clamp ((stamina/STAMINA_DIVIDER), STAMINA_MIN ,STAMINA_MAX );
        transform.position += transform.forward*4.0f*Time.deltaTime*staminaTemp*Speed;

        timeToPass -= Time.deltaTime;

        if ( timeToPass < 0.0f && NoOneInFront( oponents ) ) {
            timeToPass = UnityEngine.Random.Range( 1.0f, 5.0f); 
            state = Player_State.PASSING;
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("pass");
            timeToBeSelectable = 1.0f;
            temporallyUnselectable = true;
        }

        float distance = (goalPosition.position - transform.position).magnitude;
        Vector3 relative = transform.InverseTransformPoint(goalPosition.position);

        if ( distance < 20.0f && relative.z > 0 ) {

            state = Player_State.SHOOTING;
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("shoot");
            timeToBeSelectable = 1.0f;
            temporallyUnselectable = true;

        }

    }

    void LateUpdate() {

        // turn head if necesary
        Vector3 relativePos = transform.InverseTransformPoint( sphere.gameObject.transform.position );

        if ( relativePos.z > 0.0f ) {

            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (sphere.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1.0f,0) - headTransform.position);
            headTransform.rotation = lookRotation * initialRotation ;           
            headTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3( headTransform.eulerAngles.x, headTransform.eulerAngles.y,  -90.0f);

        }

    }

    void  Update() {

        stamina += 2.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        stamina = Mathf.Clamp(stamina, 1, 64);      

        switch ( state ) {


            case Player_State.PREPARE_TO_KICK_OFF:
                transform.LookAt( new Vector3(sphere.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, sphere.transform.position.z) );
            break;


            case Player_State.KICK_OFFER:

                if ( sphere.bPassButton || this.gameObject.tag == "OponentTeam" ) {

                    GetComponent<Animation>().Play("pass");
                    timeToBeSelectable = 2.0f;
                    state = Player_State.PASSING;
                    inGame.state = InGameState_Script.InGameState.PLAYING;
                }

            break;

            case Player_State.THROW_IN:

            break;

            case Player_State.CORNER_KICK:

            break;

            case Player_State.CHANGE_DIRECTION:

                if ( !GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("turn")) {
                    gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = true;
                    transform.forward = -transform.forward;
                    GetComponent<Animation>().Play("rest");
                    state = Player_State.CONTROLLING;
                }

            break;


            case Player_State.CONTROLLING:
                if ( gameObject.tag == "PlayerTeam1" ) 
                    Case_Controlling();         
            break;

            case Player_State.OPONENT_ATTACK:
                Case_Oponent_Attack();          
            break;


            case Player_State.PICK_BALL:
                transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 5.0f;

                if (GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("fight") == false) {

                    if ( gameObject.tag == "OponentTeam" )
                        state = Player_State.OPONENT_ATTACK;
                    else
                        state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;

                }

            break;


            case Player_State.SHOOTING:

                if (GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("shoot") == false)
                    state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;


                if (GetComponent<Animation>()["shoot"].normalizedTime > 0.2f && sphere.owner == this.gameObject) {
                    state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;
                    sphere.owner = null;
                    if ( gameObject.tag == "PlayerTeam1" ) {
                        sphere.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(transform.forward.x*30.0f, 5.0f, transform.forward.z*30.0f );
                        barPosition = 0;
                    }
                    else {

                        float valueRndY = UnityEngine.Random.Range( 4.0f, 10.0f );
                        sphere.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(transform.forward.x*30.0f, valueRndY, transform.forward.z*30.0f );
                    }

                }
            break;

            case Player_State.PASSING:

                if (GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("pass") == false)
                    state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;


                if (GetComponent<Animation>()["pass"].normalizedTime > 0.3f && sphere.owner == this.gameObject) {
                    sphere.owner = null;

                    GameObject bestCandidatePlayer = null;
                    float bestCandidateCoord = 1000.0f;


                    if ( gameObject.tag == "PlayerTeam1" ) {

                        foreach ( GameObject go in players ) {

                            if ( go != gameObject ) {
                                Vector3 relativePos = transform.InverseTransformPoint( new Vector3( go.transform.position.x, go.transform.position.y, go.transform.position.z  ) );

                                float magnitude = relativePos.magnitude;
                                float direction = Mathf.Abs(relativePos.x);

                                if ( relativePos.z > 0.0f && direction < 5.0f && magnitude < 15.0f && (direction < bestCandidateCoord) ) {
                                    bestCandidateCoord = direction;
                                    bestCandidatePlayer = go;

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        foreach ( GameObject go in oponents ) {

                            if ( go != gameObject ) {
                                Vector3 relativePos = transform.InverseTransformPoint( new Vector3( go.transform.position.x, go.transform.position.y, go.transform.position.z  ) );

                                float magnitude = relativePos.magnitude;
                                float direction = Mathf.Abs(relativePos.x);

                                if ( relativePos.z > 0.0f && direction < 15.0f && (magnitude+direction < bestCandidateCoord) ) {
                                    bestCandidateCoord = magnitude+direction;
                                    bestCandidatePlayer = go;       
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    if ( bestCandidateCoord != 1000.0f ) {

                        sphere.inputPlayer = bestCandidatePlayer;
                        Vector3 directionBall = (bestCandidatePlayer.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
                        float distanceBall = (bestCandidatePlayer.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude*1.4f;
                        distanceBall = Mathf.Clamp( distanceBall, 15.0f, 40.0f );
                        sphere.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(directionBall.x*distanceBall, distanceBall/5.0f, directionBall.z*distanceBall );

                    } else {
                        // if not found a candidate just throw the ball forward....
                        sphere.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward*20.0f;

                    }



                }
                break;
            case Player_State.GO_ORIGIN:

                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running");
                // now we just find the relative position of the waypoint from the car transform,
                // that way we can determine how far to the left and right the waypoint is.
                Vector3 RelativeWaypointPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector3( 
                                                            initialPosition.x, 
                                                            initialPosition.y, 
                                                            initialPosition.z ) );

                // by dividing the horizontal position by the magnitude, we get a decimal percentage of the turn angle that we can use to drive the wheels
                inputSteer = RelativeWaypointPosition.x / RelativeWaypointPosition.magnitude;

                if ( inputSteer == 0 && RelativeWaypointPosition.z < 0 )
                    inputSteer = 10.0f;

                transform.Rotate(0, inputSteer*10.0f , 0);
                float staminaTemp = Mathf.Clamp ((stamina/STAMINA_DIVIDER), STAMINA_MIN ,STAMINA_MAX );
                transform.position += transform.forward*3.0f*Time.deltaTime*staminaTemp*Speed;          transform.position += transform.forward*3.0f*Time.deltaTime;

                if ( RelativeWaypointPosition.magnitude < 1.0f ) {
                    state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;                    
                }


            break;

            case Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC:

                timeToRemove += Time.deltaTime;             
                float distance = (transform.position - initialPosition).magnitude;

                // know the distance of ball and player 
                float distanceBall = (transform.position - sphere.transform.position).magnitude;

                // if we get out of bounds of our player we come back to initial position
                if ( distance > maxDistanceFromPosition ) {

                    Vector3 RelativeWaypointP = transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector3( 
                                                                initialPosition.x, 
                                                                initialPosition.y, 
                                                                initialPosition.z ) );


                    inputSteer = RelativeWaypointP.x / RelativeWaypointP.magnitude;


                    if ( inputSteer == 0 && RelativeWaypointP.z < 0 )
                        inputSteer = 10.0f;

                    transform.Rotate(0, inputSteer*20.0f , 0);
                    GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running");
                    float staminaTemp2 = Mathf.Clamp ((stamina/STAMINA_DIVIDER), STAMINA_MIN ,STAMINA_MAX );
                    transform.position += transform.forward*5.5f*Time.deltaTime*staminaTemp2*Speed;

                } // if not we go to Ball...
                else {

                    Vector3 ball = sphere.transform.position;
                    Vector3 direction = (ball - transform.position).normalized;
                    Vector3 posFinal = initialPosition + ( direction * maxDistanceFromPosition ); 

                    Vector3 RelativeWaypointP = new Vector3(posFinal.x, posFinal.y, posFinal.z);

                    // go to Ball position....
                    if ( distanceBall > 5.0f ) {
                        RelativeWaypointP = transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector3( 
                                                                    posFinal.x, 
                                                                    posFinal.y, 
                                                                    posFinal.z ) );

                    } else if ( distanceBall < 5.0f && distanceBall > 2.0f ) {

                        // if we are less than 5 meters of ball we stop
                        RelativeWaypointP = transform.InverseTransformPoint(new Vector3( 
                                                                    transform.position.x, 
                                                                    transform.position.y, 
                                                                    transform.position.z ) );

                    // if we are too close we go back with special animation
                    } else if ( distanceBall < 2.0f ) {

                        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("jump_backwards_bucle");
                        state = Player_State.ONE_STEP_BACK;
                        break;

                    }

                    inputSteer = RelativeWaypointP.x / RelativeWaypointP.magnitude;

                    if ( inputSteer == 0 && RelativeWaypointP.z < 0 )
                        inputSteer = 10.0f;

                    if ( inputSteer > 0.0f )
                        transform.Rotate(0, inputSteer*20.0f , 0);


                    // this just checks if the player's position is near enough.
                    if ( RelativeWaypointP.magnitude < 1.5f ) {

                        transform.LookAt( new Vector3( sphere.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, transform.position.y ,sphere.GetComponent<Transform>().position.z)  );
                        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("rest");     
                        timeToRemove = 0.0f;

                    }   else {          


                        if ( timeToRemove > 1.0f ) {                    
                            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running");
                            staminaTemp = Mathf.Clamp ((stamina/STAMINA_DIVIDER), STAMINA_MIN , STAMINA_MAX );
                            transform.position += transform.forward*5.5f*Time.deltaTime*staminaTemp*Speed;
                        }
                    }


                }

            break;



            case Player_State.RESTING:

                transform.LookAt( new Vector3( sphere.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x, transform.position.y ,sphere.GetComponent<Transform>().position.z)  );
                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("rest");           

            break;




            case Player_State.ONE_STEP_BACK:

                if (GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("jump_backwards_bucle") == false)
                    state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;

                transform.position -= transform.forward*Time.deltaTime*4.0f;    

            break;


            case Player_State.STOLE_BALL:

                Vector3 relPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint( sphere.transform.position );
                inputSteer = relPos.x / relPos.magnitude;
                transform.Rotate(0, inputSteer*20.0f , 0);

                GetComponent<Animation>().Play("running");
                float staminaTemp3 = Mathf.Clamp ((stamina/STAMINA_DIVIDER), STAMINA_MIN ,STAMINA_MAX );
                transform.position += transform.forward*4.5f*Time.deltaTime*staminaTemp3*Speed;


            break;


            case Player_State.TACKLE:

                if ( GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("tackle") ) {

                    transform.position += transform.forward * (Time.deltaTime * (1.0f-GetComponent<Animation>()["tackle"].normalizedTime) * 10.0f);

                } else {

                    GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("rest");
                    temporallyUnselectable = false;
                    state = Player_State.MOVE_AUTOMATIC;

                }

                break;


        };


        // after pass or shoot player get in a Unselectable state some little time
        timeToBeSelectable -= Time.deltaTime;

        if ( timeToBeSelectable < 0.0f )
            temporallyUnselectable = false;
        else
            temporallyUnselectable = true;

    }


    void OnCollisionStay( Collision coll ) {

        if ( coll.collider.transform.gameObject.tag == "Ball" && !gameObject.GetComponent<Player_Script>().temporallyUnselectable ) {

            inGame.lastTouched = gameObject;
            if ( state == Player_State.TACKLE ) {

                sphere.transform.position += transform.forward;

            }

            Vector3 relativePos = transform.InverseTransformPoint( sphere.gameObject.transform.position );

            // only "glue" the ball to player if the collision is at bottom
            if ( relativePos.y < 0.35f ) { 

                coll.rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
                GameObject ball = coll.collider.transform.gameObject;
                ball.GetComponent<Sphere>().owner = gameObject;

                if ( gameObject.tag == "OponentTeam" ) {
                    state = Player_Script.Player_State.OPONENT_ATTACK;
                }


            }
        }

    }

    void OnGUI() {

            if ( sphere.timeShootButtonPressed > 0.0f && sphere.inputPlayer == this.gameObject) {

                Vector3 posBar = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint( headTransform.position + new Vector3(0,0.8f,0) );
                GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect( posBar.x-30, (Screen.height-posBar.y), barPosition, 10 ), barTexture );

                barPosition = (int)(sphere.timeShootButtonPressed * 128.0f);
                if ( barPosition >= 63 )
                    barPosition = 63;

            }

            if ( sphere.owner == this.gameObject ) {

                Vector3 posBar = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint( headTransform.position + new Vector3(0,1.0f,0) );
                GUI.DrawTexture( new Rect( posBar.x-30, (Screen.height-posBar.y), (int)stamina, 10 ), barStaminaTexture );
                stamina -= 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script is way too big; you need to split it into smaller ones, to make it easier for you to work with.

The error is telling you that you have are trying to declare a variable with a name that has already been used within that scope. I'm not looking through your long code to find exactly what you're doing, but it's something along the lines of this:

```
if (...)
{
    float distanceBall;
}

float distanceBall;
```

You need to give one of them a different name or declare it beforehand like so:

```
float distanceBall;

if (...)
{
    ...
}

...
```